# What is the Closed Form of $\sum_{n = a}^b k^{f(n)}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, recurrence-relations, finite-differences

I recently used discrete calculus to derive the following formula:
$$
\sum_{n = a}^b k^n = \frac{k^{b + 1} - k^a}{k - 1}.
$$

I know that the [simple chain rule does not work for discrete calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235680/chain-rule-for-discrete-finite-calculus) (and so there is no u-substituion analogue that I am aware of), so I am unable to derive a closed-form formula for the following expression:
$$
\sum_{n = a}^b k^{f(n)}.
$$

My question is whether or not the above expression has a closed form and what that closed form is.
I know that the expression may not have a closed form in general, but I am wondering if there are certain types of functions and/or sequences that allow the above sum to have a closed form.

Comment: Well, if $f$ is a linear function, you can do the same trick. If it is quadratic, perhaps looking at theta functions might tell you some stuff..

Comment: Make $f(n)=\log_k(g(n))$ to ask which $\sum\limits_{n=a}^b g(n)$ have a closed form? Try searching [summatory function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=summatory+function)