# The Chain Rule in Multivariate Partial Hasse Derivatives

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, finite-fields, polynomial-rings

Let $f\in R[x]$ (where $R$ is a unital ring), we can define a map $D:R[x]\to R[x]$ called the "Hasse Derivative" as:

$$D(f) = \sum_{i=1}^n i a_i x^{i-1}$$

In this case, we can show that there is "chain rule" for the Hasse derivative:$$D(f\circ g) = D(f)\circ g \cdot D(g)$$

The Hasse derivative can then be extended to the Multivariate Partial Hasse Derivative (MPHD) which defines the following map:

$$D_i:R[x_1,\cdots,x_n]\to R[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$$
$$D_i(f)= D(f^{(i)})$$

Where $f:R[x_1,\cdots,x_n]\to R[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, and $f^{(i)}$ is the "univariate part" polynomial in $x_i$ having fixed the other $x_j$ to some value in $R^{n-1}$.

Now suppose, we had a function $F: R^n\to R^m$ given by $m$ coordinate functions $f_i: R^n\to R$. It is then possible to define a "Hasse Jacobian" $J_F$ given by the matrix:

$$ J_F = \left( \begin{matrix} D_1(f_1) & D_2(f_1) & \cdots & D_n(f_1) \\ D_1(f_2) & D_2(f_2) & \cdots & D_n(f_2) \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ D_1(f_m) & D_2(f_m) & \cdots & D_n(f_m) \end{matrix} \right) $$

My question is, then, is there a chain rule for the Hasse Jacobian, ie. some relationship equating $J_{F\circ G}$ to expression with $J_F, J_G$ and $G$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's the same as the usual chain rule and it's much easier to establish in this algebraic setting. (I'll take $R$ to be commutative for safety, though.) Adjoin an infinitesimal $\varepsilon$ satisfying $\varepsilon^2 = 0$; then $D = \frac{d}{dx}$ can be defined via the identity

$$f(x + \varepsilon) = f(x) + \varepsilon D(f(x))$$

and similarly for the partial derivatives. (This gives quick and easy proofs that $D$ is linear and satisfies the product rule; a good exercise if you haven't seen this before.) For a polynomial function $F : \mathbb{A}^n \to \mathbb{A}^n$ we can similarly define the Jacobian via

$$F(v + \varepsilon w) = F(v) + \varepsilon J_F(v) w$$

which allows for a very straightforward and intuitive proof and derivation of the chain rule:

$$\begin{align*} (F \circ G)(v + \varepsilon w) &= F \left( G(v) + \varepsilon J_G(v) w \right) \\
 &= F(G(v)) + \varepsilon J_F(G(v)) J_G(v) w \\
 &= (F \circ G)(v) + \varepsilon J_{F \circ G}(v) w \end{align*}.$$

so we get $J_{F \circ G}(v) = (J_F \circ G)(v) J_G(v)$ as expected. Similar proofs are available in calculus using asymptotic notation but here they are particularly simple; we really get to consider first-order expansions only and ignore higher-order terms by fiat.

I am not familiar with the term "Hasse derivative" for this operation; Wikipedia uses this term for a [slightly different map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_derivative), and the term I've seen is [formal derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_derivative) (although that Wikipedia article is a bit strange). But see the Wikipedia article on [derivations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(differential_algebra)) for more.

Comment: This is a great approach, I asked this question as an extension of the same question in the particular case where R = GF(2), if you're interested in explaining how this idea works when there already is an index 2 nilpotent element in the ring. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4525377/multivariate-finite-difference-chain-rule-in-gf2-polynomials

Comment: @T Pluck: I don't understand what's going on there. 1) $\mathbb{F}_2$ has no nonzero nilpotents, so that construction isn't an example of this construction. 2) Yrogirg only considers polynomial *functions* on $\mathbb{F}_2$; the identities I just described apply to *polynomials* over an arbitrary commutative ring, in particular to polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_2$ (not polynomial functions). The product and chain rules don't hold for the finite difference for polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: Okay, maybe I do understand. When considering polynomial *functions* over $\mathbb{F}_2$, repeatedly applying $x^2 = x$ shows that every polynomial function is equal, as a function, to an affine polynomial (constant + linear). The finite difference produces the linear part.

Comment: You're right about nilpotency, I'm confusing multiplication with addition.

Okay, so I'm interested in polynomial functions on GF(2)^n not abstract polynomials, I'm working with a finite difference approach (although it'd be nice if the infinitesimal method could be applied here), and I want a chain rule for a Jacobian over those partial finite difference operators. Maybe I need to find a better way to ask my question again.

Comment: https://math.berkeley.edu/~reiddale/differential_algebra_notes.pdf - these notes seem to really closely match your argument

Comment: @T Pluck: the chain rule in this context should follow directly from my previous comment: every polynomial function on $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ is equal to an affine polynomial and the finite difference isolates the linear part.